# Bootstrap modal does not pop up after adding table plugin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on node.js and using bootstrap for designing. Initially my modal was working fine. But after adding tableSorter plugin, when i click click on a link to open a modal, my whole screen becomes black and modal is not visible on screen.

Here is the code I have used

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#addProjectModal" class="openAddModalDialog btn btn-primary  btn-custom-darken"> + Add project</a>
<div id="addProjectModal" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Enter project details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body ">
    <form id="project-form" method="POST" action="/" class="form-horizontal well form-inline span6  custom-form">
      <div class= "row">
        <div class = "control-group">
          <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="projId">Project Id</label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input name="projId" placeholder="Project id" class="form-control  input-xlarge"><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `hide` class from the modal div:
`<div id="addProjectModal" class="modal fade in" style="display: none; ">`